# CSS file does not render properly on Amazon S3

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket hosting a simple website serving 1 HTML file & 1 CSS file.

The HTML file seems to be able to locate the CSS file, but the problem is that the CSS file is not rendering correctly for some reason when uploaded to S3 and loaded on a browser. Lines are messed up and center background color extends out all the way to the edge. It looks fine when the same files are opened locally on a browser.

I have tried:

- opening with different browsers
- making sure metadata is correct for the css file
- re-uploading via Console & AWS CLI

Rendering on S3 (not rendering right):
[image: rendering on s3]

Rendering on local (the way it should be):

[image]

metadata content-type: text/css:

[image: metadata content-type: text/css]

bucket hosting checked:
[image: bucket hosting checked]

What could be causing this?

Comment: Browser cached an old version?

Comment: I tried different browsers and devices. Same issue. Files render fine locally, but not on S3. Also, changes do show up if I make some changes to the files and re-upload to S3.

Comment: How are you referring to the CSS file (src ref) in your HTML? Does the browser dev tools network tab show any issues? If you view the CSS file actually downloaded (via the network tab) is it correct?

Comment: @jarmod Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!


What fixed the issue for me:

Browser dev tools network tab showed "mixed content" error on another third party CSS(url) the HTML file was pointing to. "This request had been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." 

So the main CSS file I uploaded to S3 wasn't the issue, but the third party CSS file which had a non-https URL. I downloaded the CSS file, uploaded to S3, and updated the HTML file to get it from S3 instead of original URL.

Comment: This page was very helpful:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

Comment: Great, glad you resolved the problem. If you're able to write an answer, then it's worth doing that and accepting it. Also, always worth upvoting helpful comments and helpful answers to guide future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. The way I resolved it was by omitting "/" in the CSS reference since it did not have a containing folder in my S3 bucket. It seems regular text editors can automatically do this somehow? I was referring to my CSS file like this --> `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css">` and then omitted the "/" resulting in ---> `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">` and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the mimeType of the file served from S3 was not text/css.  From the file in S3's web interface, goto "Object actions" -> "Edit metadata" and create a new Metadata with Type=System defined, Key=Content-Type, Value=text/css